# Elastic search update illegal_argument_exception

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've a little issue when trying to update an ES document.

Currently, my php update methode look like :
and i got this error :

```
  {"error":{"root_cause":

[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[DVcjUVo][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason
  ":"failed to execute script","caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"runtime error","script_stack":["if (ctx._source.prices_list.5 == null) { ","
          ^---- HERE"],"script":"if (ctx._source.prices_list.5 == null) { ctx._source.list.5 = [params.new_price_data] } else { ctx._source.list.5.add(params.new
  _price_data) }","lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null}}},"status":400}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access to the property 5 of the object prices_list but you say yourself that your remove this object just before update.

`if (ctx._source.prices_list.5 == null)` VS `ctx._source.remove('prices_list')`

You cant check a property of a non-existing object.